# I need authenticate on next14 with your own backend?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, next.js, next-auth

Olá

I  have my own backend that asks for my email and password and returns a token if it's correct.
I wanted to create this back and front connection using Spring boot and Next14, but after this update I didn't know how to do this!

Is the best solution for this to use next-auth?

Do I need to create a custom provider to use my own backend?

I tried to create it using credentials, but I don't know what else to do...

```
const LoginForm = () => {
    const handleSubmit = async  (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
        const response = await signIn('credentials', {
            email: formData.get('email'),
            password: formData.get('password'),
            redirect: false
        })
        console.log(response)
    }
 }
```

Comment: If your backend is Spring Boot you don't need anything more than a fetch call to the API to get a token. Next Auth is more for using Next.js server-side capabilities.